# Emojis are not displaying in email body using mandrill API

Tags: php, html-email, emoji, mandrill

As someone is adding emojis in text-area from mobile , it's not displaying well in email. Instead of showing emojis it's displaying character like ðŸ˜‚ðŸ¤£ðŸ˜ƒ.

Can anyone help to handle emojis dynamically thanks

Comment: hello, you need to be more specific.
Which mobile platform, which specific application, which server applications ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you want to do, **show your code** so we can see what have you have tried so far.

Comment: @altagir Composing message from Android mobile and sending to gmail email address, using php mandrill library for email sending

Comment: It could be the email client is not able to decode UTF-8.  You could also try the solution presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752752/how-can-i-send-cyrillic-emails-with-mandrill-and-windows1251-encoding

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply an UTF-8 issue in that the characters aren't being handled properly.

Comment: I have already set the content type as UTF-8 in email template and also tried the email message body pass to the utf8_encoding function , but it's not work for me